# Enable Learning Paths in Scratch Org

Tags: scratch-org-definition-file, learning

Which feature/setting must be enabled in Scratch Org Definition to enable [Learning Paths](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customhelp_lex_learning_intro.htm&type=5)?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying using definition file to enable Learning Path in scratch org while creating?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I don't think it is possible because don't see any setting available as per the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Org Shape](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_create_shape.htm)?

If that doesn't work, you could automate that with this plugin:
https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-browserforce-plugin